# How does the fail(String message) method behave when its called twice in a Test

Tags: testng, junit5, assertion

I read in the documentation, that the Method "Fails a test with the given failure message." . I found some code containing 2 fail statements.  Am I correct, to believe, that the second statement would never be called, if the first one fails and thus ends the test? What would happen, if the first fail() does not fail? Could the test pass, if the second fail() occurs?

I did some trying and believe the second fail never gets executed.

```
@Test
public void testIllegalArguments(){
try {
    new House("", 50);
    fail("ExampleText");

    new House("123", -1);
    fail("exampleText");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `fail()` is never going to get executed because the execution aborts as soon as an Exception or an Error is raised (`AssertionError` is thrown when you call `fail()`)